# Fetching one row in database

Tags: php

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Distinct(specificcategoryname) FROM `clientstable` c,specificcategories s where c.PhoneNumber=:phNo and c.SpecificCategoryId=s.SpecificCategoryId');
$stmt->execute(['phNo'=>$phNo]);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['specificcategoryname']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

I have code like this need to fetch only one specific value from the database. how can i get the preferred value?

Answer (score 0):

Your, where clause is matching with more than one records that's why more than one records are fetching. if you want to select specific single record then there should be change in sql query. I can't more help because, i need to see the complete schemas of both tables ( clientstable and categorytable) that you are using. Thank you